# NSScrollView Accessibility issue in 10.9

Tags: objective-c, macos, accessibility, voiceover, nsscrollview

I'm writing a macOS app in Objc.

I have a NSScrollView with a button A in its documentView ,and a view B have the same super view as my scroll view(NSScrollView).

I want to press key board (control + option + right arrow) to from A to B ,which does not access the scroll view when Voice Over On.

When I am in MacOs 10.10+ ,the only thing I need to do is

`[scrollView setAccessibilityElement:NO];`

In 10.9,I try to use

```
[scrollView accessibilitySetOverrideValue:@"" forAttribute:NSAccessibilityRoleAttribute];
```

But when I use it,I can't do anything to the button that inside the scrollView.
Would you have any solutions can help me do it in macOS 10.9? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`- (BOOL)accessibilityIsIgnored;` set it return YES